# Issue with looping over elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a function which gives me data and then I can loop over them. In windows browser I get data like this

```
$('.js-igb-modal'); // k.fn.init [div#ImageModal_4a97acaf-6ec2-4178-a377-a39d39ad57eb.modal.fade.image-modal-lg.image-gallery-modal.j…, prevObject: k.fn.init(1)]
```

When I do the same call in iphone safari broswer (connected from mobile to chrome inspect tools) I get this

```
<div class="modal fade image-modal-lg image-gallery-modal js-igb-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" id="ImageModal_c218c53b-51d5-4bf8-8b12-79205eaf6aaa" data-gallery-id="c218c53b-51d5-4bf8-8b12-79205eaf6aaa">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div id="slider_c218c53b-51d5-4bf8-8b12-79205eaf6aaa" class="flexslider slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <div class="slides__item">
                            <div class="slides__item__a">
                                <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/1-fra-biblioteket.jpg" title="Utdeling 3STA" alt="Utdeling 3STA">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="flex-caption">
                                <h3>Utdeling 3STA</h3>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="slides__item">
                            <div class="slides__item__a">
                                <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/3-tilhorerne.jpg" title="Familie og venner" alt="Familie og venner">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="flex-caption">
                                <h3>Familie og venner</h3>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="slides__item">
                            <div class="slides__item__a">
                                <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/3sta-2.jpg" title="3STA" alt="3STA">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="flex-caption">
                                <h3>3STA</h3>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="slides__item">
                            <div class="slides__item__a">
                                <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/3stb.jpg" title="3STB" alt="3STB">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="flex-caption">
                                <h3>3STB</h3>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="slides__item">
                            <div class="slides__item__a">
                                <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/3stc-3.jpg" title="3STC" alt="3STC">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="flex-caption">
                                <h3>3STC</h3>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="slides__item">
                            <div class="slides__item__a">
                                <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/3std-2.jpg" title="3STD" alt="3STD">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="flex-caption">
                                <h3>3STD</h3>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="slides__item">
                            <div class="slides__item__a">
                                <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/3stt-3.jpg" title="3STT" alt="3STT">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="flex-caption">
                                <h3>3STT</h3>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="slides__item">
                            <div class="slides__item__a">
                                <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/4-tilhorere.jpg" title="Familie og venner" alt="Familie og venner">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="flex-caption">
                                <h3>Familie og venner</h3>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="slides__item">
                            <div class="slides__item__a">
                                <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/4bysk.jpg" title="4BYSK" alt="4BYSK">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="flex-caption">
                                <h3>4BYSK</h3>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="slides__item">
                            <div class="slides__item__a">
                                <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/4hysk.jpg" title="4HYSK" alt="4HYSK">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="flex-caption">
                                <h3>4HYSK</h3>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="slides__item">
                            <div class="slides__item__a">
                                <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/pba-2.jpg" title="3PBA" alt="3PBA">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="flex-caption">
                                <h3>3PBA</h3>
                            </div>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="carousel_c218c53b-51d5-4bf8-8b12-79205eaf6aaa" class="flexslider carousel">
            <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/1-fra-biblioteket.jpg?w=202&amp;h=130&amp;mode=crop" title="Utdeling 3STA" alt="Utdeling 3STA" tabindex="0">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/3-tilhorerne.jpg?w=202&amp;h=130&amp;mode=crop" title="Familie og venner" alt="Familie og venner" tabindex="0">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/3sta-2.jpg?w=202&amp;h=130&amp;mode=crop" title="3STA" alt="3STA" tabindex="0">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/3stb.jpg?w=202&amp;h=130&amp;mode=crop" title="3STB" alt="3STB" tabindex="0">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/3stc-3.jpg?w=202&amp;h=130&amp;mode=crop" title="3STC" alt="3STC" tabindex="0">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/3std-2.jpg?w=202&amp;h=130&amp;mode=crop" title="3STD" alt="3STD" tabindex="0">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/3stt-3.jpg?w=202&amp;h=130&amp;mode=crop" title="3STT" alt="3STT" tabindex="0">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/4-tilhorere.jpg?w=202&amp;h=130&amp;mode=crop" title="Familie og venner" alt="Familie og venner" tabindex="0">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/4bysk.jpg?w=202&amp;h=130&amp;mode=crop" title="4BYSK" alt="4BYSK" tabindex="0">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/4hysk.jpg?w=202&amp;h=130&amp;mode=crop" title="4HYSK" alt="4HYSK" tabindex="0">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img class="flexslider-lazy" src="/Static/img/Spinner-1s-50px.svg" data-src="/siteassets/nyhetsbilder/2018-19-nyhetsbilder/2018-19-avgangsseremoni/pba-2.jpg?w=202&amp;h=130&amp;mode=crop" title="3PBA" alt="3PBA" tabindex="0">
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I am confuse why I don't get the same data type back? The issue is that in later I cannot run .each to loop over elements.

Comment: Make sure that jQuery is actually loaded on the iPhone/Safari and that your code runs *after* jQuery is loaded. `console.log($.fn.jquery)` should print the jQuery version and I bet it does not on your iPhone test device.

Comment: The first output is expected when the variable holds a jQuery object. The latter would appear to hold an Element object. This would explain why you cannot use jQuery `each()` method on the latter - it's not a jQuery object.

Comment: console.log($.fn.jquery) gives me back undefined.

Comment: Can you please show a full example, as `$` must be a reference to jQuery in the first example for the statement not to throw an error

Comment: @mohsinali1317 Well, then clearly jQuery is not loaded, as I had said. `$` exists as a helper function that is a shorthand for `document.querySelector()` when jQuery has not overridden `$`. Check the network errors and the script timing.